# Replacing a slice of several elements in a list with one element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I am trying to find a slice, of variable size, in a list and replace it with one element:

```
ls = ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
lt = ['b', 'c']
r = 'bc'

for s,next_s in zip(ls, ls[1:]):
    for t, next_t in zip(lt, lt[1:]):
        if (s, next_s) == (t, next_t):
            i = ls.index(s)
            ii = ls.index(next_s)
            del ls[i]
            del ls[ii]
            ls.insert(i, r)
            print (ls)
```

This works only sometimes, producing:

```
['c', 'bc', 'd', 'c']
```

but if `lt = ['d', 'c']` and `r = 'dc'`, it fails producing:

```
['b', 'c', 'c', 'dc']
```

How to fix that? Or what is a better way to handle this?

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will edit to highlight that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way that might work for you (depends on whether `lt` can appear multiple times and on what to do then).

```
ls = ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
lt = ['b', 'c']
r = 'bc'

for i in range(len(ls)):
    if ls[i:i+len(lt)] == lt:
        ls[i:i+len(lt)] = [r]
        print(ls)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. It is very unlikely that `lt` would appear multiple times, but what if it does?

Comment: Then it depends on whether or not it overlaps. If it doesn't overlap, then this code still works fine.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Right, then it still works fine (assuming replacing all appearances is desired), the loop just goes unnecessarily far (which it does anyway, since I'm lazy and prefer simple code :-).